# "Perfect singleton" via using sync.Once?

Tags: go, synchronization

i am confusing that, is below snippet perfect?

```
import "sync"
import "sync/atomic"

var initialized uint32
var instance *singleton

var instance *singleton
var once sync.Once

func GetInstance() *singleton {
    once.Do(func() {
        instance = &singleton{}
    })
    return instance
}
```

`atomic.StoreUint32(&initialized, 1)` will flush instance to all CPUs?
i think i need add an atomic store and load for instance, like below snippet

```
var instance *singleton
var once sync.Once

func GetInstance() *singleton {
    once.Do(func() {
        atomic.StorePointer(&instance, &singleton{})
    })
    return atomic.LoadPointer(&instance)
}
```

i think Once.Do is only guarantee execute function f one time.
and `atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)` is only memory barrier for o.done. 
it doesn't ensure `instance` is global visible

```
func (o *Once) Do(f func()) {
    if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 1 {
        return
    }
    // Slow-path.
    o.m.Lock()
    defer o.m.Unlock()
    if o.done == 0 {
        defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)
        f()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "perfect singleton"?  Most people consider singletons to be an anti-pattern, so kind of the opposite of perfect. Is there a problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the goal is here. How is this better than simply initializing `instance`, like `var instance = &singleton{}`?

Comment: Package initialization (including evaluation of expressions and the assignment in variable declarations) happens safely, in a single goroutine, before that variable can be accessed. As JimB pointed out, there is no need for that code kung-fu unless your real initialization is more complex and you only want to execute that on-demand.

Comment: Even if you require more complex initialization, using atomics to `flush instance to all CPUs` doesn't make sense. You need synchronization, which `sync.Once` provides.

Comment: I think this isn't as crazy as some people may think. Each CPU has a cache and lockless algorithms normally have to be worried about what a cache on a CPU may have. That being said, its not necessary here. But I don't think its great to say it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @poy: this isn't a "lockless algorithm", nor can atomics be used to ensure what each thread views with a simple store because they don't provide synchronization points in the memory model. Just writing something atomically (even if it guarantees cache coherence) doesn't mean the thread waited around for that to happen.  Now you could safely loop over a Load, or CompareAndSwap to block while waiting for the value to be written, but then you've just re-implemented a Mutex for discernible reason.

Comment: @JimB I agree with all your points. Thats why I said "its not necessary here" for this not being a lockless algorithm. Lockless algorithms have to employ various strategies for polling memory to wait for things to have changed. I would rather put this sort of information out here though instead of saying memory syncing between CPUs isn't a thing (because it certainly can be).

Comment: @poy: sorry, I hadn't read your answer yet, thanks for clarifying. I was referring specifically to the described use case, as like you said, atomics and memory coherence are real issues, they're just not relevant here.

Comment: as far as know, atomic.Store(write barrier) only store data to store buffer of CPU and flush to L1 cache asynchronously and then send a invalid message to other CPUs. atomic.Load(read barrier) will block read until consum all invalid message from invalidate queue. So, that is why atomic.Store and atomic.Load should be used together. in the implementation of once.Do, it only flush store buffer to L1 cache and send invalid message to other CPUs, so might be i need't to use atomic.StorePointer(&instance,&singleton{}), but ` return atomic.LoadPointer(&instance)` is necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets break down your question to two pieces:

1. Singletons
2. Atomics and the Go memory model

### Singletons

Go has package level variables. These are instantiated before anything has the chance to get moving, therefore if you good with these things being created as soon as the package is used, you get a singleton for free.

```
package somepack

var(
  connection = createConn()
)

func Connection() SomeConnection {
  return connection
}
```

`connection` will be created once and therefore `Connection()` will return the same instance of it safely.

Sometimes developers reach for a singleton when they want "lazy" instantiation. This is a good idea if the resource is expensive to create and not always needed. This is where `sync.Once` is useful.

```
var (
  connection SomeConnection // Not instantiated
  connectionOnce sync.Once
)

func Connection() SomeConnection {
  connectionOnce.Do(func(){
    connection = createConn()
  })

  return connection
}
```

Notice I'm not doing anything special with the assignment (e.g., `atomic.Store()`). This is because `sync.Once` takes care of all the locking required for this to be safe.

### Atomics and the Go memory model

A good resource to start with is the published docs for this: [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem)

Your concern of "flushing" to the different CPUs is valid (despite some of the comments) because each CPU has its own cache with its own state. C++ (among other languages like Rust) developers tend to care about this because they get to. Go developers don't get to care AS much because Go only has "happens before". Rust in fact has some nice [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html) on it.

That being said, you normally don't need to worry about it. A mutex (and `sync.Once`) will force the state of the memory on each CPU to be what you would expect.

Comment: i think Once.Do is only guarantee execute function f one time. and atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1) is only memory barrier for o.done. it doesn't ensure instance is global visible

Comment: Once uses locks though which will force each CPU to refresh it's cache.

Comment: if locks will force each CPU to refresh its cache, why need `atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)` ? 
just need `o.done=1`

Comment: Well you don't need to use both. Atomics are more of a "hardware" lock and are an alternative to locks. They are used in lockless algorithms, which honestly is quite hard to get right.

Comment: once.Do use both, you can check it. 
So, i don't think so.

Comment: Once uses an atomic to try and "skip" the mutex. A mutex is more expensive as it can block and wait for the lock to become available. An atomic will take a fixed number of clock cycles because it doesn't block. So really it is an optimization the library did for you.

Comment: Once :  `defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)` is extra? As you said, it should be changed to `o.done=1` because locker will ensure cache coherence.

Comment: Correct. If you only take what they called the slow path then you don't require the atomics because you are never accessing the memory outside of the mutex.

Comment: So, in https://golang.org/src/sync/once.go : 
`defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)` should be changed to `o.done=1`
??? So, go author wrote no sense code

Comment: No. I said they have an optimization with the fast path

Comment: sorry, i still don't understand.
the 40 line of source (https://golang.org/src/sync/once.go), they have used lock,but 43 line of source, they also used atomic. i don't know where it's optimization as you said

Comment: So before they enter the lock they read from an integer via atomics. If that value is set, they bail and never enter the lock. If it is not set they enter the lock and eventually set the integer. Now they have to use atomics because if a different go routine calls the function, it will read that integer. To do that safely they use atomics. So to safely read that memory outside of a lock, both the read and write (even though the write happens to be within a lock) have to be via atomics.

Comment: i known this condition `if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 1` is in order to reduce the frequency of lock.Lock(). 
but you have said `defer o.m.Unlock()` will ensure cache coherence, and `defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)` also will ensure cache coherence, so, `defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)` is extra because `defer o.m.Unlock()` will be called after set 1 to o.done.

Comment: Well not quite. So the `Unlock()` will only serve you if when you read from the memory you have first called `Lock()`. This means that when you load memory, the CPU and compiler have been instructed based on the locking that they must ensure the memory is up to date. Just calling `Unlock()` on its own will not ensure this. Atomics and locks have different strategies on how they instruct the compiler and hardware to handle memory.

Comment: so, in my second snippet, `atomic.StorePointer(&instance, &singleton{})` and `atomic.LoadPointer(&instance)` are usefull, because it ensure all CPUs update their caches.

Comment: No I don't believe so. The Once ensures that the only place that `instance` is being modified is always going to happen before it being read. Therefore any read after the first will always have the latest memory (as it was only changed the one time) and the CPUs' cache will have been updated via either the fast or slow path of the Once.

Comment: you said "CPU's cache will have been updated in Once function", and only lock.Lock() ensure memory is up to date, but `atomic.StorePointer(&instance,&singleton{})` is in behind of it.
and if `defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)` is usefull , why is `atomic.StorePointer(&instance,&singleton{})` useless?

Comment: Because you get the once fast path for free. Their code already ensures the happens before state for you and therefore you don't have to worry.

Comment: as far as know, atomic.Store(write barrier) only store data to store buffer of CPU and flush to L1 cache asynchronously and then send a invalid message to other CPUs. 
atomic.Load(read barrier) will block read until consum all invalid message from invalidate queue. So, that is why atomic.Store and atomic.Load should be used together.

in the implementation of once.Do, it only flush store buffer to L1 cache and send invalid message to other CPUs, so might be i need't to use `atomic.StorePointer(&instance,&singleton{})`, but ` return atomic.LoadPointer(&instance)` is necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, however at the very least I think the race detector will be unhappy

Comment: how to free resources on application close? like if its a database singleton and I want to free the connection, how to write destructor function?

Comment: @gauravarora There isn't a homerun answer here. Typically this is where people use context.Context. When the context is cancelled, the resource is cleaned up. But even then there are some issues with this. If the main go routine exits for example, you may not have time to finish cleaning up. Therefore you need something like a WaitGroup to block the main go routine.

Comment: can you provide an example code for this? near about for production sanity? I am not able to figure out this snippet with full confidence for golang. @poy
I understand its not a homerun, but just asking about golang tools and kit. Context documentation and tryout examples are still difficult for me to understand with the current official documentation and test cases given by golang-community.